# How do you solve this type of error "IndexError: index 799 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 799"?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Billion-scale semi-supervised learning project for image classification. The general process is as follows:

The first step is to train an initial teacher model A using labeled data;

The second step is to use teacher model A to make predictions on unlabeled data, sort the images of each category label, select the best K to construct a new training data set, that is, a pseudo-labeled dataset;

There are more steps ahead, but when the second step was performed, the above error message was reported. The role of the `select_top_k` function is - the key-value pairs extracted from the json file are arranged in descending order of the key elements, and the first k elements are selected, and the program runs to this place and an error occurs.

The specific error information is as follows:

```
Load Model Accuracy: 75.64 Load Model end epoch: 100
class name: apple
image data count: 210
class name: aquarium_fish
image data count: 203
class name: baby
image data count: 151
class name: bear
image data count: 189
...
class name: wolf
image data count: 212
class name: woman
image data count: 199
class name: worm
image data count: 173
Saving.. sampling_dict
label: 39
each label item count: 18779
label: 82
each label item count: 18779
label: 20
each label item count: 18626
label: 0
each label item count: 18340
label: 9
each label item count: 13232
label: 6
each label item count: 5547
label: 3
each label item count: 17344
label: 16
each label item count: 4228
label: 2
each label item count: 17960
label: 24
each label item count: 1880
label: 10
each label item count: 1581
label: 5
each label item count: 14524
label: 4
each label item count: 16767
label: 61
each label item count: 799
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "make_sample_data_1.py", line 155, in <module>
main(args)
File "make_sample_data_1.py", line 148, in main
select_top_k(args.k)
File "make_sample_data_1.py", line 128, in select_top_k
sampled_image_dict["all"].append([all_items[index][0], int(key)])
IndexError: index 799 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 799
```

Related code snippets:

```
  1 def select_top_k(k=1000):
  2     sampled_image_dict = {}
  3     sampled_image_dict["all"] = []
  4     with codecs.open("./sampling_dict.json", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
  5         load_data = json.load(f)
  6 
  7         for key in load_data.keys():
  8             print("label: ", key)
  9             all_items = load_data[key]
 10             all_items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
 11             all_items = np.array(all_items)
 12             print("each label item count: ", len(all_items))
 13             for index in range(0, k):
 14                 sampled_image_dict["all"].append([all_items[index][0], int(key)])
 15 
 16     print("Saving.. selected image json")
 17     j = json.dumps(sampled_image_dict)
 18     with open("selected_image.json", "w") as f:
 19         f.write(j)
```

[Note]  The error message is on line 14.

Comment: if you have 799 items, their index ought to be 0 to 798. 799 is indeed out of range. I do not understand why you don't get this error much earlier, for the previous sets.

Comment: What do you understand from that error? _[Note] The error message is on line 14._ Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: Reply to LSerni: There is no error in the original larger than 789 like " label:  4    each label item count: 16767;  label:  5     each label item count:  14524". I'm also confused why there is an error in this place of "799".  Reply to AMC: The entire error output was already listed in the question section. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are looping from 0 to k and by default you are setting k to 1000.  When you reach data that has less than 1000 records it will fail as soon as it reaches the limit.

You could either set k to a lower number like 500 or change your code like the below to make sure that k is never higher than the length of all_items.

Another option is making K a percentage of the all_items and just do that instead of taking the top 1000.

Code below to make sure that k never exceeds the length of your all_items.

```
  1 def select_top_k(k=1000):
  2     sampled_image_dict = {}
  3     sampled_image_dict["all"] = []
  4     with codecs.open("./sampling_dict.json", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
  5         load_data = json.load(f)

  6 
  7         for key in load_data.keys():
  8             print("label: ", key)
  9             all_items = load_data[key]
 10             all_items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
 11             all_items = np.array(all_items)
    ## make sure if you have data less than k it uses a smaller amount.
                if len(all_items) < k:
                    k = len(all_items)
 12             print("each label item count: ", len(all_items))
 13             for index in range(0, k):
 14                 sampled_image_dict["all"].append([all_items[index][0], int(key)])
 15 
 16     print("Saving.. selected image json")
 17     j = json.dumps(sampled_image_dict)
 18     with open("selected_image.json", "w") as f:
 19         f.write(j)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After I tried the two methods you proposed, this kind of errors still existed. Details are as follows. Firstly,  I tried the first method you proposed. I set k to a lower number like 500 or even lower like 50, same error occured as before: "IndexError: index 799 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 799". Secondly, after I changed the code as you said, although there were no previous errors, there were new errors of the same type as before. The error message is "IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4".  So, I'm extremely confused at this moment.

Comment: I tweaked the answer to so that it sets a max of k based on the len of all_items instead of load_data, since that is what you are looping through.  It really seems like the index is getting too high and it makes sense from your output that sometimes the data you are looping through is too small.  If that doesn't work i would recommend adding more debug code, catch the exception and print out the index, or use an IDE like pycharm where you can step through the code.